# Material icons do not work in Angular 17?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular17, mat-icon

Icons don't work in Angular.

In the *component.ts* file:

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard-space',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatIconModule,
  ],
```

And in the HTML file:

```
<div class="w-[20rem] h-[20rem] bg-yellow-100">
  <mat-icon>grade</mat-icon>
</div>
```

and what I see is the text: "gra"

Of course, I ran `npm install --save @angular/material`.

But the console is empty.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Had you added the Material Icon stylesheet: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` in index.html?

Comment: yes sir! i didnt since its not described in docs but now it works! thanks sir for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Getting Started with Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started),

> The `ng add` command will additionally perform the following actions:
>
> Add the Material Design icon font to your *index.html*

Ensure that the Material icon stylesheet is included in the *index.html*, if not you need to add it manually.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```